# Behaviour of sizeof operator in C

Tags: c, struct, sizeof

I am getting unusual behaviour with my code, which is as follows

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct a
{
    int x;
    char y;
};
int main()
{   
   struct a str;
   str.x=2;
   str.y='s';
   printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(int),sizeof(char),sizeof(str));
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

For this piece of code I am getting the output:

```
4 1 8
```

As of my knowledge the structure contains an integer variable of size 4 and a char variable of size 1 thus the size of structure a should be 5. But how come the size of structure is 8.
I am using visual C++ compiler.
Why this behaviour?

Comment: In `printf()` arguments you really should cast the `sizeof` values to `(int)` ... or `(unsigned long)` and use `"%lu"` ... or, if you have C99, use `"%zu"`.

Comment: @pmg: Exactly. Because `sizeof()` returns a value of type `size_t`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is called [Structure Padding](http://clinuxpro.com/structure-padding)

Having data structures that start on 4 byte word alignment (on CPUs with 4 byte buses and processors) is far more efficient when moving data around memory, and between RAM and the CPU.

You can generally switch this off with compiler options and/or pragmas, the specifics of doing so will depend on your specific compiler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: _You can generally switch this off_, but I recommend never to do so, even if you need to parse some binary packet and have an idea to create a similar struct for effortless encoding/decoding. Remember, that on some targets (maybe in the past only) unaligned reading could lead to processor crash! Also this makes your code fully unportable.

Comment: @Yury: if the compiler allows `#pragma pack` or similar stuff on such platforms, normally it will generate code to workaround the aligned read problem (typically `memcpy` to a separate, aligned location), otherwise such structures would be unusable.

Answer (score 8):

The compiler inserts padding for optimization and aligment purposes. Here, the compiler inserts 3 dummy bytes between (or after) your both members.

You can handle the alignment with `#pragma` directive.

Comment: perhaps (1) 3 bytes and (2) after

Comment: Yes, it's 3 bytes in this case, but I think it's between, isn't it ?

Comment: well, it depends on the endianness of the target machine :) either iiiidddc or iiiicddd.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly to illustrate how this padding actually works, I've amended your program a little.

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct a
{
  int x;
  char y;
  int z;
};
int main()
{   
   struct a str;
   str.x=2;
   str.y='s';
   str.z = 13;

   printf ( "sizeof(int) = %lu\n", sizeof(int));
   printf ( "sizeof(char) = %lu\n", sizeof(char));
   printf ( "sizeof(str) = %lu\n", sizeof(str));

   printf ( "address of str.x = %p\n", &str.x );
   printf ( "address of str.y = %p\n", &str.y );
   printf ( "address of str.z = %p\n", &str.z );

   return 0;
}
```

Note that I added a third element to the structure. When I run this program, I get:

```
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$ ./padding 
sizeof(int) = 4
sizeof(char) = 1
sizeof(str) = 12
address of str.x = 0x7fffc962e070
address of str.y = 0x7fffc962e074
address of str.z = 0x7fffc962e078
amrith@amrith-vbox:~/so$
```

The part of this that illustrates padding is highlighted below.

```
address of str.y = 0x7fffc962e074
address of str.z = 0x7fffc962e078
```

While y is only one character, note that z is a full 4 bytes along.